# Play/Pause not working spotify

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, keyboard, spotify

I run Ubuntu 16.04 dual booted with macOS Mojave on a 2013 macbook pro. Up until a week or so ago, the play/pause/skip keys worked perfectly with Spotify. Now they aren't responsive at all. I recently updated to Mojave on my mac side but I don't know if that's the issue. Restarting does not help. Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. Not sure why is stopped working, but here's how to get it working again. Go into keyboard shortcuts and re-create custom shortcuts:

Play/Pause toggle:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

Previous:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous
```

Next:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
```

Comment: Worked really well, however I got my original keyboard shortcuts to work by first testing one of the above commands in a terminal. It somehow woke up my system and made the keys work. Did not reboot yet, so will have to see if it is persistant. I am running Mate on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Please refer to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105363/spotify-keyboard-controls-not-working/1105364#1105364