# Spotify keyboard controls not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, spotify, shortcut-keys

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, I cannot play, pause, go to the next or the previous song in spotify. There are many answers but most are complicated, is there a simple solution that doesn't require a command line?

I have a Logitech bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: All I had to do is Close Google Chrome or any browser that had Youtube or any media playing, for my buttons to work with Spotify, then re-open browser

Comment: @anadoba answer is AWESOME everyone. Check that first!

Comment: @digitalextremist Ok I accepted his answer to push it to the top, but I haven't tested it since the answer was posted 2 years after I asked the question.

Comment: @Lynob very cool of you to do. I actually just provisioned a new workstation and came right back to this to use the advice again :) Nice of you to keep updating this excellent question you asked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The top-voted solutions are about adding a custom key mapping, which is kinda cumbersome, as you have to drop every other binding related to the Play/Pause key.
There's only one binding possible for a key so it means that your Play/Pause key stops working anywhere outside Spotify.

Initially, I wanted to do that, but Ubuntu settings didn't let me create a binding so the key was used/captured by something else on my system.
It turned out that Chrome captures hardware media keys by default :)
You can disable this functionality by opening
`chrome://flags/`
and then disabling
`Hardware Media Key Handling` feature.

After doing so, your Play/Stop key along with Next and Previous keys are handled by Ubuntu itself again.
It fixed the issue for me. Now Spotify is the one to capture these keys.

This also happens on Firefox, you can access the option in:
`about:config`
Then, change
`media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled` to `false`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: This is it! The media keys are working but captured by chrome even if there is no player/youtube on it

Comment: This solution works for all chromium browsers, including Brave. Thanks!

Comment: It also worked for me! Thanks

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: It works, thanks ! Too bad we have to choose between Spotify and Chrome...

Comment: WHAT. A. NINJA. I have been looking for the easy solution to this forever. THANK YOU. Do not care to have Brave / Chrome media controls at all, so glad to pull that support. BAM.

Comment: Accepting this answer as everyone on this thread seems to agree that this is the best answer. I haven't tried it personally, as this answer was posted 2 years after I asked the question.

Answer (score 82):

Here is another link i have found that help me and its the same solutions as [k2shah](https://askubuntu.com/users/964634/k2shah) mention it, but with more details.

Instead of downloading the spotify_control, you use the D-Bus commands. Before you add it as a new keyboard command, feel free to execute those commands.

Play/Stop

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

Next

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
```

Previous

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous
```

Once you validate the above commands, feel free to add them as Key Shortcut. 
For Ubuntu, "Settings > Devices > Keyboard" than add (+) and put the name and copy the commands, than put the keyboard shortcut.

[TheLink](https://fabianlee.org/2016/05/25/ubuntu-enabling-media-keys-for-spotify/)

Comment: for next/prev worked like a charm, but for play/pause the audio play/pause key shortcut it doesn't work. If I remap it to 'super + ;' or other modifier + non-func key works. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Check if that map is already taken for something else.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04 I was unable to set custom shortcuts to those keys since they were already used by other keyboard shortcuts (upon prompt for pressing keyboard combination nothing was happening when I was pressing Play/Stop button, not even the info line). I had to manually unset them using gsettings set command and then I was able to set it up. You can find the ones to unset in gsettings list-recursively (grep the result).

Comment: On Ubuntu 22 I don't find the `+` to add custom shortcuts.

Answer (score 38):

There is a simple solution credit goes to [this thread on Spotify forum](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Linux-keyboard-shortcuts/td-p/1626394), Thanks to  **schuellerf**  and **rszabla**. The solution is pretty simple and works on any Linux distribution.

1. Download [this file](https://community.spotify.com/spotify/attachments/spotify/desktop_linux/296/1/spotify_control.zip), extract it and make it executable `chmod a+x spotify_control`
2. Place it anywhere you want, I'll assume that it is placed in Downloads folder
3. Go to settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts -> custom shortcuts

[image]

4. Add new shortcut by clicking the plus button, I'll override the default play/pause/next and previous keys because I only listen to music on spotify, If you need those shortcuts then assign different ones for Spotify

[image]

The command you see in the picture above is for 'play/pause' function

`/home/your_username/Downloads/spotify_control playpause`

The commands that are available

1. `/home/your_username/Downloads/spotify_control playpause`
2. `/home/your_username/Downloads/spotify_control previous`
3. `/home/your_username/Downloads/spotify_control next`
4. `/home/your_username/Downloads/spotify_control play`
5. `/home/your_username/Downloads/spotify_control stop`

Please note that you have to do this

`/home/your_username/Downloads/spotify_control playpause`

Because

`~/Downloads/spotify_control playpause`

That won't work, at least not in Ubuntu 16.04, unity desktop, the shortcut manager doesn't seem to understand the tilde `~`

Comment: this worked for me, thx! quick info of my system: ubuntu 16.04 and using an apple (wired)keyboard

Comment: What about "Don't Play This Song" shortcut for playlists?

Comment: Worked on 18.04 with spotify installed via snap. thanks

Comment: Its work on Fedora 34, but just play/pause command not worked for me? If any have a solution for me please tell me.

Comment: I found the solution, This keyboard shortcut set to for two command

Answer (score 7):

All i had to do in Fedora is 
`sudo dnf install playerctl`

Anyway, it works in Ubuntu, no idea why such a basic functionality is missing here.

Answer (score 6):

Considering the Aiphee Answer on ubuntu or Debian this works!

```
sudo apt install playerctl
```

Package info: utility to control media players via MPRIS
https://packages.debian.org/buster/playerctl

Comment: Now you can add custom shortcut like `playerctl play` and first available player will play. I tested youtube + spotify.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. After install I did `playerctld daemon` then the command `playerctl -l` returnd `spotify`. I've started Spotify, played a song, and tried `Ctrl-Right Arrow` to get next song, it didn't work. Am I missing smth ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to download a file and keep it around (for whatever reason)
you can just assign the key to the command that's run in the file

I set up a new custom keybind

Name: Spotify Play/Pause

Command:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

for the other commands just replace the `PlayPause` with `Stop`, `Next`, or `Previous`

Answer (score 0):

You can call the D-Bus command directly.

- Open `System settings`
- Go to `Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts`
- Select `Edit -> New -> Global Shortcuts -> D-Bus Command`
  *( the button is at bottom )*
- Set name : `Spotify-Next`
- Bookmark Trigger: set shortcut by Your choice
- Bookmark Action:

  - Remote application: `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify`
  - Remote object: `/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2`
  - Remote object: `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next`

For Previous use `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous`

For Play/Pause uset `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause`

You can test it with Call button
More is

> [here](https://medium.com/@blomsmail/take-the-bus-how-to-control-spotify-with-the-terminal-43f7bd44aed1)

Thanks to IvanAK .